# В php вывести значение которого нет в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как вывести в php значение SUM(VIEWS) общее количество просмотров каждого пользователя 
если оно сумируется через ssql запрос 
Функция

```
function get_top_users()


$query = db()->query("SELECT id , SUM(views) , entity_id, username, first_name, last_name, gender, country, avatar, online_time, featured FROM feeds,users WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 90 DAY )AND id = entity_id GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY SUM(`views`) DESC LIMIT 30");
return fetch_all($query);
```

Вывод пользователей *( выводятся только сами пользователи а мне нужно число вывести sum(Views)

```
<?php foreach(get_top_users(10) as $user):?>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo get_user_name($user)?>" href="<?php echo profile_url(null, $user)?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_avatar(200, $user)?>)"></a>
            <?php endforeach?>
```

Скриншот из ssql запроса где выводится ообщее количество просмотров 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте имя для суммы (алиас) и пользуйтесь этим именем что бы получить это значение из запроса `select id, SUM(views)  as sum_views, ...` ... Если вы конечно об этом спросили. И не понятно что делают функции вроде get_user_name, только не говорите что просто `$user['name']` получают ...

Answer (score 0):

Для таких случаев если не знаете что делать, можете сделать var_dump() переменной. В данном случае вы увидите что вы можете обратиться к этому значению через $user['SUM(views)']